# facebook - how to auto login with user information?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to create a gallery app.
Flow:

- Login facebook
- Redirect my app
- Get albums
- Save information of albums to database

The problem is that I want the relationship between album and user is 1:1

my album contain photos from varied facebook's album

exactly : 1 myalbum : 1 user : n facebook's album

So I can save informations of user, when need to login, app will get informations in the database and login with that information.

In the current system, I have to type the email and password to login to faceboook. If I login with another email, I can't get albums of first account.

Album table: album_id user_id

User table : user_id , user ....

Any solution ?

Comment: I really don't know what you mean. Is the problem really a 1:1 album:user issue? Isn't it rather an n:1 connection?

Comment: maybe some confuse, my album contain photos from varied facebook's album 1 myalbum : 1 user : n facebook's album

Comment: Try offline access permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user's album is private, you'd need to fetch each image in the album and save it to your server (you'd also need to request the offline_access extended permission). However, I'm not sure this allowed (you'd need to review fb's TOS).

Edit: Assuming you're trying to display album's from another user - not meta data thats already saved in your db.

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with a 3rd party "App" or purely working with the Facebook API? Sounds like you need to store the users token, not user/pass.